# Type hinting mypy in list comprehension over duck-typed content

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, duck-typing

I have a (nested) list comprehension, and receive an error from mypy.

In my list comprehension, I am iterating over a list which is guaranteed to contain only instances of two types (that don't implement the same base; in the example below called `A` and `B`).
The instances of both types are guaranteed to have the same attribute `name` which I utilize in the list comprehension. Mypy cannot automatically infer the type of the list, considers the content of the list mere `objects` (only common base), and thus warns, that the attribute `name` is not defined in instances of `object`.

I broke down my code into the following example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass 
from typing import Union, Set, List

@dataclass
class A:
    name: str

@dataclass
class B:
    name: str

# Approach 1:
c: Union[A, B]
f : Set[str] = {c.name for c in [A('1'), B('2')]} # error: "object" has no attribute "name"  [attr-defined]


# Approach 2:
d: List[Union[A, B]] = [A('1'), B('2')]
g : Set[str] = {c.name for c in d} # No issue!
```

In approach 2, mypy is not reporting an error. Why is this the case, and why is the type hint for `c` in The approach 1 not sufficient?

Sadly, in my real use-case, the list `d` is only intermediate (does not have a name) and I cannot type hint like in approach 2. Is there a way to hint mypy that accessing `name` is actually viable without needing to transform the list comprehension into a loop?

I am using python3.8.

Comment: Do you have access to `A` and `B` (do they come from your code rather than from some external library)? If so, you have a [simple solution](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=9c8d626ed09f1b6bf2ff40f115989b96)

Comment: No, sadly I cannot modify the real `A` and `B` by moving the shared part of the interface into a shared superclass. To solve the issue & get rid of the error I could make a nested for loop for now, but would prefer keeping the list comprehension

Comment: [Type join over type union](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12056) strikes again...